# XSL template copy and add elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

```
<ComponentGroup Id="SimulatorComponentGroup">
   <Component Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
       <File Id="fil763F3807501181AEBB3384E197DA1B60" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\aeStatGridWeights.txt" />
   </Component>
   <Component Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
       <File Id="fil52CCB4416F79DAB20B21723321A693FD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\afStatGridWeights.txt" />
   </Component>
   <Component Id="cmp8EFEB6EE1903B8CF488FED2D3754A8CF" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
       <File Id="fil035410628EFD654283E0E6A32D1985C4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\anr_black_ag1_dl65_p80_sc1.ate_config" />
   </Component>
```

I would like to create a template which outputs the following:

```
<ComponentGroup Id="SimulatorComponentGroup">
    <Component Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
        <File Id="fil763F3807501181AEBB3384E197DA1B60" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\aeStatGridWeights.txt" />
        <RemoveFolder Id="cmpCAB8CD4B3E3F5DE9BD27E4BE2C6D4ED5" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
        <RemoveFolder Id="cmp9FA0A11B61A218ED2C433E82749C7264" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
        <File Id="fil52CCB4416F79DAB20B21723321A693FD" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\afStatGridWeights.txt" />
    </Component>
    <Component Id="cmp8EFEB6EE1903B8CF488FED2D3754A8CF" Directory="Simulator" Guid="*">
        <RemoveFolder Id="cmp8EFEB6EE1903B8CF488FED2D3754A8CF" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
        <File Id="fil035410628EFD654283E0E6A32D1985C4" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.SimulatorSourcePath)\anr_black_ag1_dl65_p80_sc1.ate_config" />
    </Component>
```

Here is my *.xsl file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:wix="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">


  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>


  <xsl:template match="@*|*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />


 <xsl:template match="wix:Component[@Directory='Simulator']">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:attribute name="Id">
        <xsl:value-of select="./Id"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <RemoveFolder Id=""></RemoveFolder>
      <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when I use copy i'm deleting the **Id** and **Directory** from the Component attribute and also how can i copy from `Compnent Id="` the Id into the `attribute`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think your question is quite clear, but perhaps this can get you on the right path:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Component">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="{@Id}" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note in the template matching "Component":

1. applying templates to copy the existing attributes and child nodes;
2. using the *attribute value template* to get the value from Component/@Id into RemoveFolder/@Id.

---

### Edit:

In order to place `<File>` (or any existing child node) **after** `<RemoveFolder>` and `<RegistryValue>`, change the second template to:

```
<xsl:template match="Component">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
        <RemoveFolder Id="{@Id}" On="uninstall" />
        <RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]" Type="string" Value="" KeyPath="yes" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: is there a way to change the order of the attributes. so <File> attribute would be last to appear and not first?

Comment: @Gilad `<File>`is an **element**, not an **attribute**. Why is the order important? It shouldn't make any difference.

Comment: i'm using WIX which is the windows installer and the order does matter over there. congrats on the 9K points